# Why does Install Shield Limited Edition Require Crystal Report?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports, installshield

I have a project which uses the target .NET Framework 4.5.2 but does not use the Crystal Report nor is any of the Crystal Report library being reference in any of the assembly.

When I created Install Shield Installer, I selected the [**.NET Framework 4.5 Full Package**] as a requirement. When I install it is generating the following error.

```
-6058 Error Merging SAP Crystal...
```

I was forced to add the [**SAP Crystal Report runtime engine for .NET Framework 4**] in the Redistributables list.

Is there anyway to avoid using the Crystal Report merged in my installer? The requirement only has "**4.5 Full Package**" in the option which I suspect is causing the need for Crystal Report. Is there a partial one?

Comment: Do you have a reference to a Crystal Report assembly or DLL in one of the projects within your solution?

Comment: @R.McMillan Actually I do not have any reference in my DLLs